# Prevent duplicate data in Webix File Manager?

Tags: file-manager, webix

Can we prevent duplicate names of files and folders in the same folder
to avoid data replication? Is there any built-in
functionality in `Webix File Manager`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve it by myself. You can prevent duplicate data by controlling response which contain "id" and "value" with a new id and a new file name. You can control it at backend in my case MVC controller.